# Support of a discrete measure

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_measure) (and some books), a discrete measure on the real line is a measure $\mu$ whose support $\text{supp}(\mu)$ is at most a countable set.

This definition seems to be inconsistent with the commonly [admitted definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_measure#Definition_and_properties). I believe that the word 'support' sould be replaced by 'atom'. Namely, the support is in this case the closure of the atoms. These two sets can differ, see the following.

I have this counterexample in my mind, is it correct?

> Take a measure which atoms are exactly the rational numbers. Then the atoms are concentrated on a countable set, but its support is not countable anymore.

Comment: what exactly bothers you withe the term "support"? besides, a measure does not need to be defined on $\mathbb{R}$ or a subset of it

Comment: For simplicity purposes I only considered a measure on the real line. Now I added some precision about the support and atoms.

Comment: @user190080 The problem with the word "support" is that, at least according to a very standard version of the definition, the support of something is a _closed_ set.

Comment: You're exactly right, people should not use the word "support" here. More correct is to say that a discrete measure is a measure which is _concentrated on_ a countable set.

Comment: Good! Then this question can be closed :) Thanks @DavidC.Ullrich for the confirmation.

Comment: @user81566 I see, good question...did you continue reading the support article? Some problems which are arising are discussed and also a different support definition suggested